# How do I make an API call server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've created a client-side application that makes an API call. The issue with this, however, is that in order to make the API call, I have to use an API Key. If I make the call client-side, the user will be able to see the API key. How do I avoid this? Well, if the answer is to call the API server-side, how do I do that? There seems to be little information wherever I look regarding server-side programming, and if anyone could lead me in the right way, it would be great.

Comment: Look at [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) or [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

Comment: note: if your client side will call server with without any key (and internally server side will call other api with key) - you're opening option to abuse your client side to use this protected api by anyone

Comment: @IłyaBursov How do I get around this? How do I access an API without allowing anyone else to?

Comment: @athariandre there are multiple options each with its own pros and cons, so it is impossible to answer without details

Comment: You could start with the official documentation and guides: [Making HTTP requests with Node.js](https://nodejs.dev/en/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set it in the header with bearer

```
    let config = {
             headers: {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + KEY
             }
    };
    Axios.get('http://url', {}, config )
    .then( (response) => {
         console.log(response)
    })
    .catch();
```

Comment: the question is about how to send the key so that any visitor can't see it

Comment: No, you can't secure your API key in a client-side app.

[This article goes into some more detail](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2016/02/15/securing-api-keys-in-a-javascript-single-page-app/)

Two options: 

1. Make the API calls server-side and then serve information to the client from there
2. Require the client use their own API keys